# jquery vertical slide expanding image gallery on a grid

Tags: jquery, image, grid, gallery

I've searched and searched for an image gallery to fit a specific set of criteria, but have had no luck.

This is a perfect example: http://theofficialbrand.com/collections/all

It is essentially the same effect as a search in google images.

A gallery of image thumbnails on a grid, the hover feature is not essential.
When clicked, a horizontal section either slides up, or expands down, displaying more content (the fullsize image on the left, and image or product information on the right.) The thumbnails don't need to be effected, simply spread vertically to allow room for the expansion. It would need the ability to contract, or disappear as well, like when another image, or product, was clicked.

I was hoping there may be a gallery that has already been developed, similar to this, as I am not incredibly familiar with writing jquery / javascript. I'm fairly capable with html, css, as well as modifying pre-written code if perhaps multiple jquery code snippets could be manipulated and combined to create this. I wanted to AVOID a lightbox, hence my interest in this type of gallery.

Maybe, I have simply been searching with the wrong terms, to find what I am looking for, or I am over complicating this. Any help would be greatly appreciated and I do hope I'm not asking something that has been addressed many times already.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

CoDrops has a new tutorial covering this: http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/03/19/thumbnail-grid-with-expanding-preview/